# Translation of Menu items

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

HI I'm trying to work out how to translate my menu items, weirdly Log Out appears to be the only one which translated from the onset. But I can't see where this was implemented. If I search for the menu name as a string in transate interface/transalte they can't be found. and editing a menu offers no extra fields for translate options??

any body know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Its another Module thats required. The Module is called [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) this allows you to customise menus/taxonomy and lots of other translation features.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you search for translations they are case sensitive. don't include aditional spaces, it has to be exact, but it can be partial.
If one translation was previously made and the same word appears in many places it will list it, but what applies is the first translation made (sorted by time)
You have to make sure that your Log Out is really a tranlation

in my case it appears in chain: /admin/settings/language as Log out @username, so if I translate this, it works in the other languages
there is another Log out in the chain with the same name...so be careful

Comment: Thanks for the tip on case sensitivity, I've used this but still I cannot pick out my menu items? Its a bit weird really, I managed to find a menu item which is listed under my User Menu and is created there from a View. But my other items just arn't available? I can see no settings under the Structure Admin menu area so I'm totally at a loss here!?